# Trying to filter an api request with <= and >= date tomorrow 0100-2400 if statement

Tags: python, datetime, for-loop, if-statement, pycharm

I am new to Python and am having a hard time filtering an api request by datetime: tomorrow basically from hours 0100-2400, only. Time zone is local time. The request prints out as a nested dictionary and I have been able to filter it down to 'validTime' but can't get it filtered anymore from there. My start_time and end_time may be wrong, or my if statement may be wrong, or it's something else. I feel that there is an easy fix for this, I just can't figure it out. Please help. My code is below:

```
import constants
import requests
import datetime
import json

today = datetime.date.today()
yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
day_after_tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
hour1 = datetime.time(1, 0, 0)
hour0 = datetime.time(0, 0, 0)

start_time = ['{}T{}+00:00/PT1H'.format(tomorrow, hour1)]
end_time = ['{}T{}+00:00/PT1H'.format(day_after_tomorrow, hour0)]

response = requests.get(constants.austinfgd, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
temperature_data = data['properties']['temperature']['values']

print(temperature_data)
```

This is what is printed out to this point:
[Printed response to temperature_data from website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WpSk.png)

```
[{'validTime': '2020-12-11T10:00:00+00:00/PT2H', 'value': 17.77777777777778},
{'validTime': '2020-12-11T12:00:00+00:00/PT1H', 'value': 16.666666666666668},
{'validTime': '2020-12-11T13:00:00+00:00/PT2H', 'value': 17.22222222222222}, 
...
```

and so on for a number of days

So, now I need to filter by `validTime` and I specifically want the hours = to and in between start_time and end_time. So, here is my code for that:

```
for v in temperature_data:
    if ['validTime'] >= start_time and ['validTime'] <= end_time:
```

At this point, pycharm is telling me to simplifiy the chained comparison and it automatically gives me this:

```
for v in temperature_data:
    if start_time <= ['validTime'] <= end_time:
        print(v)
```

At this point, the only thing that prints out is:
[Printed response to v](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjjhO.png)

Process finished with exit code 0

I need to print these values by these times only, so I can dump into a table in postgresql, to be used elsewhere.

What am I doing wrong? I have been googling this for over a week, and I give up. Time to ask for help, please help. Thank you in advance for your help.

So, I changed things up and this seems to have worked. Not sure if there is a better way to code this. And I don't understand why I need to have v['validTime'] in the if statement. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

```
tomorrow = datetime.datetime.combine(
datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1),
datetime.time(1, 0, 0),
tzinfo=pytz.UTC
```

)

```
day_after_tomorrow = datetime.datetime.combine(
datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2),
datetime.time(1, 0, 0),
tzinfo=pytz.UTC
```

)

```
start_time = tomorrow.isoformat()
end_time = day_after_tomorrow.isoformat()

response = requests.get(constants.austinfgd, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)
temperature_data = data['properties']['temperature']['values']

for v in temperature_data:
    if start_time <= v['validTime'] <= end_time:
        print(v)
```

Comment: It should be `v['validTime']` and not `['validTime']`

Comment: I just tried that an now have an error:                                                            
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/todds/Desktop/Ferg Python Projects/weather/login.py", line 55, in <module>
    if start_time <= v['validTime'] <= end_time:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'str'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Yeah i think you should compare between datetime objects rather than strings. and start_time end_time shouldn't be an array/list.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Could you please give me an example? Could you give me an example of how to make start_time an object?

Comment: Were you able to solve it or still looking for answer?

Comment: I think I got it. I will edit my post with what I came up with. Not sure if there is a cleaner way to code it. Let me know what you think. Why does v['validTime'] work? I don't understand that.